# INNER JOIN entre tablas InnoDB y MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

Estoy elaborando una base de datos por lo tanto algunas tablas tendrán como Storage Engine MyISAM y otras InnoDB.

Mi duda es la siguiente: ¿existen problemas al realizar `INNER JOIN` con tablas que manejan diferentes Storage Engine?

Comment: Sí, existen problemas: un alto coste de rendimiento en consultas que manejen muchos datos, resultados inciertos en consultas del tipo `UPDATE` o `INSERT`, y otros posibles problemas por lo demás inciertos debido a la *aventura* de mezclar. [En 2010 ya se reportó un bug debido a este tipo de prácticas](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57118), las cuales te recomiendo que trates de evitar. Lo que no entiendo es por qué no migras todo a un engine o a otro. [Esta respuesta es contundente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5476284/5587982) y tiene una alta aceptación en la comunidad de SO en inglés.

Comment: Optare por INNODB, déjame y te justifico el porque de las cosas, algunas tablas en mi base de datos solamente se manejaran consultas , y en otras se realizaran UPDATE, INSERT Y DELETE,  gracias por tu aporte

Answer (score 1):

### Respuesta corta

Sí, hay problemas, y de varios tipos y niveles, según las tablas que participen y los tipos de consultas.

Entre los problemas que puedes encontrar:

1. Resultados inciertos en consultas del tipo `INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE`
2. Un alto coste de rendimiento en consultas del tipo `SELECT` u otras que impliquen una gran cantidad de datos.
3. Posibles bugs, [como este reportado en 2010](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57118), fruto de la no recomendada práctica de mezclar tablas con diferentes engines en una misma base de datos.

Por lo general no es una buena práctica mezclar, mucho menos si se trata de algo que en muchos sistemas forma parte del núcleo mismo que da cohesión a cualquier sistema o aplicación, como es el caso de los datos.

Me preguntaría si hay algún motivo para mantener una peligrosa mezcla de dos engines diferentes, cuando se puede optar por uno o por otro... dando así uniformidad y consistencia a todo el engranaje de tu aplicación.

---

### Respuesta larga

Una pregunta parecida a la tuya fue planteada en el homólogo de este sitio en inglés. [Una de las respuestas dadas es contundente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5476284/5587982), bien documentada y tiene una amplia aceptación en la comunidad de SO. Me permitiré agregarla aquí traducida, porque explica con más detalles posibles situaciones que se podrían presentar al usar tablas entremezcladas usando `MyISAM` e `InnoDB`:

#### ASPECTO # 1: El JOIN mismo

Siempre que haya uniones que involucren `MyISAM` e `InnoDB`, las tablas `InnoDB` terminarán teniendo un comportamiento de bloqueo de nivel de tabla en lugar de un bloqueo de nivel de fila debido a la participación de `MyISAM` en la consulta y [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)<sup>*</sup> no se puede aplicar a los datos de MyISAM. MVCC ni siquiera se puede aplicar a InnoDB en algunos casos.

#### ASPECTO # 2: Participación de `MyISAM`

Desde otra perspectiva, si alguna tabla `MyISAM` se actualiza a través de `INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE`, las tablas `MyISAM` involucradas en una consulta `JOIN` se bloquearán desde otras conexiones a la Base de Datos y la consulta `JOIN` tendrá que esperar hasta que se puedan leer las tablas `MyISAM`. Desafortunadamente, si hay una mezcla de `InnoDB` y `MyISAM` en la consulta `JOIN`, las tablas `InnoDB` tendrían que experimentar un bloqueo intermitente como ocurre con las tablas `MyISAM` en la consulta JOIN por estar restringidas para la escritura.

Ten en cuenta que [MVCC aún permitirá que las transacciones READ-UNCOMMITTED y REPEATABLE-READ funcionen bien y permitan que ciertas vistas de datos estén disponibles para otras transacciones. No puedo decir lo mismo para READ-COMMITTED y SERIALIZABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13939790/491757).

#### ASPECTO # 3: Optimizador de consultas

MySQL depende de la cardinalidad del índice para determinar un plan optimizado de `EXPLAIN`. La cardinalidad del índice es estable en las tablas `MyISAM` hasta que se producen muchos `INSERT`, `UPDATE` y `DELETE` en la tabla, mediante las cuales se puede ejecutar `OPTIMIZE TABLE` periódicamente en las tablas MyISAM. ¡La cardinalidad del índice `InnoDB` NUNCA ES ESTABLE! Si ejecutas `SHOW INDEXES FROM * innodbtable *;`, verás que la cardinalidad del índice cambia cada vez que ejecuta ese comando. Eso es porque `InnoDB` hará inmersiones en el índice para estimar la cardinalidad. Incluso si ejecutas `OPTIMIZE TABLE` para una tabla `InnoDB`, eso solo desfragmentará la tabla. `OPTIMIZE TABLE` ejecutará `ANALYZE TABLE` internamente para generar estadísticas de índice en la tabla. Eso funciona para `MyISAM`. `InnoDB` lo ignora.

Mi consejo es hacer todo lo posible y convertir todo a `InnoDB` y optimizar tu configuración en consecuencia.

#### ACTUALIZACIÓN 2012-12-18 15:56 EDT

Lo creas o no, [todavía hay un reporte de bug abierto en el uso de consultas que implican tablas en  `InnoDB` / `MyISAM` durante un `SELECT FOR UPDATE`](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57118). Si lo lees, resume la resolución de la siguiente manera: ¡NO LO HAGAS!

---

<sup>* MVCC, (de sus iniciales en inglés: **M**ulti**V**ersion **C**oncurrency **C**ontrol), o  control de concurrencia multiversión, es un método de control de concurrencia comúnmente utilizado por los sistemas de administración de bases de datos para proporcionar acceso simultáneo a la base de datos y en los lenguajes de programación para implementar memoria transaccional.</sup>